# AngularJS 1.5 Controllers in Separate Files

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a hard time understanding this. I'm attempting to put controllers in separate files so that they only deal with 1 thing, ideally, a partial view

My folder structure is like this...

[image: Folder Structure]

My app.js file is like this.

```
angular.module('mikevarela', ['ui.router', 'mikevarela.controller.home', 'mikevarela.controller.about', 'mikevarela.controller.audio'])

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

$stateProvider

    .state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: '../partials/home.partial.html',
        controller: 'HomeController'
    })

    .state('about', {
        url: '/about',
        templateUrl: '../partials/about.partial.html',
        controller: 'AboutController'
    })

    .state('audio', {
        url: '/audio',
        templateUrl: '../partials/audio.partial.html',
        controller: 'AudioController'
    });
});
```

and my controllers each have a module like this...

```
angular.module('mikevarela.controller.home', [])

.controller('HomeController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.title = 'Mike Varela Home Page';

}]);
```

---

My issues comes with the intial app declaration. I don't want to have to inject all the controllers in the main array app definition, that would be cumbersome and long winded. Isn't there a way to define the controller at the controller file. Kind of like this

```
angular.module('mikevarela', []).controller('HomeController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

// stuff here

}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `angular.module('mikevarela').controller.....` in subsequent files.

> `angular.module('mikevarela',[]).controller.....`

is equivalent to redefining your app. The second param is `requires` array.

Quoting official [angular.module](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.module) docs

> requires
>   (optional)
>   !Array.=
>   If specified then new module is being created. If unspecified then the module is being retrieved for further configuration.

Answer (score 1):

**About your Controllers...**

I think you're loading the controllers incorrectly.

You don't need to declare controllers as a dependency. Rather stating `module.controller('yourController`)` makes that controller available throughout the module.

If your controllers are in separate files, all you need to do to make it available is load it in with a `script` tag. e.g.

```
<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="controller1.js"></script>
<script src="controller2.js"></script>
```

**About your Application Structure...**

This is not related to your question, but just coming from someone who's developed using Angular, I'd recommend not grouping your application by `controllers/` by rather by feature. See: https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-best-practices-directory-structure